# VCL RichEdit componet which will load table background

Tags: c++builder, vcl, richedit

I am using C++ Builder XE2.
I wish to use a RTF file to load a template into a rich edit file so I can change marked strings eg $DATE$.

I have tried both TRichEdit and TJvRichEdit and can do the string replace no problem.
TJvRichEdit also load bmp and JPG which is what I want.
However when I load an RTF file generated in word or wordpad which has cell background colour I get the formatting but not the background colour.

I had a look at the RichView componet (WHich is quite expensive for a single component ($330US).
This loads the background colour but loses the font sizing (Seems to apply its own paragraph style rather than keeping the RTF paragraph file.

Does anyone know of a decent RichText component which will load from rtf file and keep both text formatting as well as the table background and also allow image loading.

Would prefer a free componet or at least reasonable price component < $100 US.